# Artificial Neuron: question on definition and inhibited signals

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, perceptron

This is an artificial neuron of a NOT function from Rojas's ML book.  I have a question on it's behavior.  It's my understanding that the neuron produces a signal if it's inputs $x_1$ summed are $\geq 0$.

In the following picture, if $x_1$ is 0, then the threshold 0 is met and there is an 1 output signal from this neuron.  If $x_1$ is 1, then the signal is inhibited by the neuron and the threshold of 0 is met, in which the neuron should have a 1 output signal.  This does not make sense to me as I would expect the neuron to have an output of 0 if $x_1$ is 1.

[image: not]

I'm also confused on NOR as pictured:

[image: NOR]

Appreciate if anyone can provide guidance on how this neuron works with the inhibitory signal into it.  The book defines the neuron is that of McCulloch–Pitts.

Thanks

Comment: Does the book contain a proper definition of this neuron? Otherwise we can only guess, notation for this isn't standardized.

Comment: edited McCulloch–Pitts